# Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. # C LANGUAGE#

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, codeblocks

i have a Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. and i really dunno how to fix it , it says thats the problem is the line of "scanf ( " %s ",& t[i].poste);"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { int d,m,y; } dtype ;

typedef struct { char nom[10]; char prenom[10] ; char poste[00]; dtype date ; } LEM ;

int main()
{
    int n,i,j;

    printf("Liste des employes\n");
    printf("\n nombre d'employes : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    LEM t[n];

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nemploye number %d :",i);

        printf("\n nom : ");
        scanf("%s",&t[i].nom);

        printf("\n prenom : ");
        scanf("%s",&t[i].prenom);

        printf("\n poste : ");
        scanf("%s",&t[i].poste);

        printf("\n date de recrutement : ");

        printf("\n day : ");
        scanf("%d",&t[i].date.d);

        printf("\n month : ");
        scanf("%d",&t[i].date.m);

        printf("\n year : ");
        scanf("%d",&t[i].date.y);

    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("nom : %s \t",t[i].nom);
        printf("prenom : %s \t",t[i].prenom);
        printf("poste : %s \t",t[i].poste);
        printf("date de rec : %d/%d/%d \t",t[i].date.d , t[i].date.m ,t[i].date.y);

    }
}
```

Comment: C array indexes start from 0 not 1

Comment: You've got an off-by-one issue with your array/loop.  Arrays are zero-indexed, so the first element of an array is `arr[0]`, and the nth element is `arr[n-1]`.  You are accessing `arr[n]` which is out of bounds.

Comment: thanks aloot dude u saved my ass , appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If your code is correctly pasted, than you have set `poste` to be of 0 size (in line `typedef struct { char nom[10]; char prenom[10] ; char poste[00]; dtype date ; } LEM ;`). Maybe you meant it to be `10` instead of `00`?

Comment: actually i fixed that right after i posted it but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loops should start at `0` and end when `i` is less than `n` since array indexing starts at 0. In your loops first you are skipping the first element and then at the last iteration you are accessing invalid memory and you're getting the segmentation fault.

Another thing to modify is how you handle the `scanf`-s. When reading something into an array you should check that what you are going to put inside the array fits. What happens if you pass to the program a string that is larger than 9 characters? It may overflow the array and be the cause of another segmentation fault.

Comment: owh gotcha , i never tought bout that , thanks mate imma fix that